# select rows as columns of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with like this:

```
id name   date
---------------------
1  Ann    01/10/2015
2  Betty  01/31/2015
3  Charly 02/15/2015
4  David  03/30/2015
5  Ernest 04/04/2015
6  Frank  04/16/2015
7  Gale   05/02/2015
8  Jack   05/09/2015
9  Kelly  07/31/2015
```

How can I retrieve 3 rows at a time like this:

```
1  Ann    01/10/2015 2  Betty  01/31/2015 3  Charly 02/15/2015
4  David  03/30/2015 5  Ernest 04/04/2015 6  Frank  04/16/2015
7  Gale   05/02/2015 8  Jack   05/09/2015 9  Kelly  07/31/2015
```

So I have 3 rows starting with Id 1, 4 and 7

I use SQL Server 2012

Comment: Don't do that. you have a **DISPLAY** problem, which is a client-side issue. You do NOT want to hack up a hideously ugly query in the DB just so you can have some nice columns in your client. SQL's job is to store/retrieve data, not make it "pretty" for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you do this in SQL?  Nope, I agree with the comment.
Can it be done in SQL?  Certainly.

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)-1)/3 AS Rnk                     
              FROM Table1)
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rnk ORDER BY id) AS RN
               FROM cte)
SELECT a.*,b.id AS id2, b.name AS name2, b.date AS date2
          ,c.id AS id3, c.name AS name3, c.date AS date3
FROM cte2 a
LEFT JOIN cte2 b
  ON a.Rnk = b.Rnk
  AND a.RN = b.RN - 1
LEFT JOIN cte2 c
  ON a.Rnk = c.Rnk
  AND a.RN = c.RN - 2
WHERE a.RN = 1  
 ;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92624/1/0)

Using integer division with a `ROW_NUMBER()` you get a value that repeats for 3 rows that can be used to slice them up.

Edit:  `LEFT JOIN` so as to not exclude incomplete rows.

Comment: I need to do this because I have to fill a form report that has 3 columns of the same data: 
    id name date  id name date   id name date
I’m filling that form using Microsoft Report Viewer (RDLC) report

Comment: It does not work with LEFT JOIN, and with INNER JOIN It doesn't show incomplete rows